# How to do 3d programming with Blender using python

Tags: python, scripting

I am planning to learn 3d programming with Blender using python programming language.

Like i want to program some object etc. in python and when i run the script, all the created objects etc. should show in blender.

Is it possible? If yes anyone please let me know how can i achieve this.

**I would only like to know about, How i can connect Blender to the code running on my terminal via a python script.**

Thanks

Comment: Hello, just as a head's up this question is really too broad and opinion-based to be accepted on this site. You should start by following the official documentation and tutorials online, and if you have trouble achieving specific goals, you can always come back here and search if someone else already experienced the same problem. If not, feel free to ask a question about it in the most precise way possible. cheers

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the reply i would only like to know about, How i can connect Blender to the code running on my terminal via a python script.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can write an add-on for Blender in Python, write a script and execute it in Blender's Script Editor or start Blender from the command line / terminal with the [`--python`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) flag and pass the path to the script. In every case you will want to learn how Blender's Python API works, which is documented in the [API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html).